# ASP.NET MVC 5 - let admin change other users password. Password changed in database but can't login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm told to make admin have a functionality to change other users password without knowing their original password. I wrote a code that changes and saves password successfully in database, but when I try to login as that user I can't.

UsersController:

```
        public ActionResult ChangePassword()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ChangePassword(int id, ViewModels.ChangePasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (!SessionControlService.CheckIsLoginStillTrue(_loginsService, HttpContext))
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");

        if (!User.IsInAnyRoles("Admin", "PropertyManager"))
            return RedirectToAction("Error", "Errors",
                new { error = Facility.Web.Resources.Resources.ErrorNotHavePermission });

        var user = _userService.GetUser(id);
        if (user == null)
            return RedirectToAction("Error", "Errors",
                new { error = Facility.Web.Resources.Resources.ErrorURLNotExist });
        user.Password = model.NewPassword;
        _userService.UpdateUser(user);

        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = id });
    }
```

Why can't I use the changed password which is saved in the database to login?
How can I make this work?

Comment: Are you storing the password as plaintext? Also, show your code which does authentication

Comment: Under no circumstances should a password ever be stored as plain text. They need to be hashed and salted.

Comment: Did you try logging in with old password?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I know.I joined this company few days ago, and this is just what I got, and I'm new to c# and asp.net mvc. I will make it hash once I get this one done.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes, I can login with old password

Comment: @Paritosh Yes, its plaintext.

Comment: That means the passwords are not changed... are you able to see the new passwords in the database?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes, the password is changed in the database, but I can't use it.

Comment: We cannot possibly answer this. We have no idea what any of you methods such as `CheckIsLoginStillTrue() or `UpdateUser() user do, although it's fairly clear that what ever you doing is awful practice, and you should scrap it all, and go to the mvc site and work through the tutorials on [Security, Authentication and Authorization](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security) to understand the basics

Comment: look, you, as a new dev to c# and mvc, should not go anywhere near a user membership system. You have no idea what to do and you will only build something that will fall over and be hacked the second someone even looks at it. Get someone experienced to deal with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC5, password is hashed... you cannot save a plaintext password like that.

You need to use these two methods:

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(...);
var token = manager.GeneratePasswordResetToken(userId)
manager.ResetPassword(userId, token, newPassword)
```

You could also try `ApplicationUserManager.UpdatePassword(...)`, or `RemovePassword(...)` and `AddPassword(...)`

`ApplicationUserManager` is normally in `IdentityConfig.cs`